# How to remove thousand separator in woocommerce prices

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, separator

I would like to display prices without thousand separator (NOT like this €1,698.00). How to disable this comma?

Comment: You can set it in settings of woocommerce please go to this link http://docs.woothemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/WooCommerce-Settings-General-Currency.png

Answer (score 1):

You can go to WooCommerce > Settings > Catalog > Pricing Options. Just remove comma for field 'Thousand Separator'.

Comment: It doesn't work. Saving changes after deleting comma brings it back.